# Assign sequence of symbols into a variable/string in Python

Tags: python, string, symbols

this sequence of symbols is required as a password in an app:

> 9h/#13/'!O!Nr},w_T0 6!ws%N\c^i,4"

How can store this to a variable/string?

Comment: It looks to me that it already is a string. Please make your question more clear. What is the source of those symbols, and why does it seem hard to convert that sequence to a string? Just what do you mean by "process"?

Comment: you cannot just assign it into a variable because the symbols make it look partly like a comment/string/regex. Could you implement pls if it seems straightforward to you?

Comment: You should read python tutorial first. If you're baffled by something this basic, you won't be able to do much else. See: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way to store those characters in a string is to use Python's triple-quotes.

```
s = '''9h/#13/'!O!Nr},w_T0 6!ws%N\c^i,4"'''
```

If your sequence did not end with a double-quote, triple double-quotes could also have been used rather than the triple single-quotes above. The triple-quote way of showing a string is designed for tough cases like yours, with almost any combination of text characters allowed in the string. Executing the command `print(s)` gives the output that you want:

```
9h/#13/'!O!Nr},w_T0 6!ws%N\c^i,4"
```

Comment: trying this, i am still getting
> '9h/#13/\'!O!Nr},w_T0 6!ws%N\\c^i,4" '
there is an additional \ character on the 8th spot

Comment: There is also an extra back-slash by the other back-slash near the end. You apparently typed `s` at the Python prompt, which shows the *representation* of the string, which you can also get with `print(repr(s))`. That is what you could type into Python to get your string--a different way to handle some of the strange characters, a method called "escaping" which was mentioned in Katarina's answer. You can be assured the the string stored in Python is what you see from `print(s)`.

Answer (score 2):

Just declare a string as usual, and escape the special characters `'` and `"` with `\`. The escape makes it act like a string literal, rather than a special character.

`str = '9h/#13/\'!O!Nr},w_T0 6!ws%N\c^i,4\"'`

Output is

`'9h/#13/\'!O!Nr},w_T0 6!ws%N\\c^i,4"'`

Comment: its not the same: there is an additional '\' on the 8th character of the string

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure that you can avoid this, since you have both quote types in the string, but you need one of them to quote the string itself. you need to escape it to tell python it is a string literal and not the ending quote. Can you disallow one of the quote types for passwords? That would make things much easier

Answer (score 1):

```
Import strings
Strings = string.punctuation
```

Use this and thank me later

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).